# Rounding a timestamp to midnight of the next day

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Given a timestamp, what would be the most elegant solution to round that date **up** to the nearest midnight of the next day?

For example `1374246685` (19/07/13 10:11:25) would be rounded to `1374296400` (20/07/13 00:00:00).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520404/how-do-i-find-the-unix-timestamp-for-the-start-of-the-next-day-in-php. Answer there is: $tomorrowMidnight = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j') + 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more elegant than Pete's solution:

```
$tomorrowMidnight = strtotime('tomorrow');
```

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php - you can do lots of fancy stuff with that :)

Comment: While that is pretty elegant it's not what I was after, that will give me tomorrow's midnight rather than the midnight of the next day of the passed in timestamp. :)

Comment: Nevermind, forgot you can pass in a timestamp in the second parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) can do this nicely:-

```
$midnight = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(1374246685)->modify('tomorrow');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/tc2Dm)

PHP version >= 5.4 only though.

Otherwise it would be:-

```
$midnight = new \DateTime();
$midnight->setTimestamp(1374246685)->modify('tomorrow')->setTime(0, 0);
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/ZKmYW)