# How to set a cookie for the beginning of the next day, according to server time?

Tags: php, time, session-cookies

I want to set PHP COOKIE which should be stored for only one day.
Setting a cookie for one day is easier.

If the user visits the site at 6PM, then the cookie should be set for another six hours only.

```
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date+1,$year);
```

where month, date and year are from the PHP date function.
Will the above code work as i expected?

Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This would probably work (haven't tested), but keep in mind that this will use the server timezone, not the user's time.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario OP is asking for beginning of next day, not the next 24 hours.

Comment: @Boaz - You're right, I've misread that detail. It's a dupe of [How do I find the unix timestamp for the start of the next day in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520404/how-do-i-find-the-unix-timestamp-for-the-start-of-the-next-day-in-php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `strtotime()` function with the `tomorrow` keyword:

```
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
```

Comment: how to get current timestamp **now** using php strtotime? so i can test it.

Comment: @PrabhaVathi `strtotime('now')` and `time()` are equivalent.